# Trek7200: new bracket,crank,chain,&shift cables. Deraillers set Trek manual. Good stand results, but stumbles riding up incline

Tags: drivetrain-slipping

Trek 7200 Bike: new bracket, crank, chain, & shift cables. Derailleurs set to Trek manual. Good stand results, but bike stumbles riding up incline on middle of 8 gears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/75034/

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "stumbles"? Perhaps the chain is skipping on the rear cassette gears?

Comment: Clarify please - you changed the chain, chainrings, cables, but not the cassette ?  
How much mileage is on the cassette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If indeed the "stumbles" refer to the chain skipping on the rear cassette gear, a simple fix is to replace the cassette. I note that the cassette (8 speed seemingly from what I find on the net) is the part of the drivetrain that you did *not* mention changing. Its gears wear just as do the chainrings on the crank. Similarly to the crankset, the middle gears tend to wear the most as they are the most frequently used.  The cassette gears and chainrings would have worn along with your previous chain, and now the new unworn chain matches the new chainrings, but not the still-worn cassette gears.
Thus, the chain is likely skipping over the still-worn cassette gear teeth, especially (or only) when under load.

Comment: Thanks Armand. Prior to replacing all the items mentioned, (plus the two rear derailleur pulleys), the bike did not slip.  After installing all the new parts, the cables and derailleurs were set up on a stand with good shifting results. (This was done twice). What I meant by stumbles is the pedals skip forward a few degrees when the torque is higher, causing a loss of momentum. I am unable to see if the chain is slipping on the cassette. The bike has less than a mile on it with the new parts. Could it be the free-wheel of the hub  as well as the cassette gears??

Comment: @Gene Your description of skipping under load sounds like the classic worn/unworn item mismatch skip. In this case, the new chain is not worn and is now a slight link to link length mismatch for the worn cassette gear teeth.  Replace the cassette and you'll be fine. These days, 8 speed cassettes are relatively cheap so you're in luck. You might also pick up a chain "stretch" measuring tool so you can monitor the wear of your chain in the future and swap in a new one when needed to reduce wear on the chainrings and cassette.

Comment: Thanks Armand and Criggie for your experienced comments. I checked my bike log excel spreadsheets going back to 1990. The 2004 bought Trek  7200, 2005 Model,  had 17,000 miles on it over 16 plus years! Amazing that it performed as well as it did. I'll change out the cassette and free-wheel and let you know what happens.

Comment: @Gene Great achievement on the mileage! The online bike specs at bicyclebluebook.com show your 2004 rear wheel hub as a Shimano RM40-8, which is technically a "freehub" style rather than a "freewheel" style (even though Shimano calls the freehub a "freewheel body"). Replacing the freehub requires taking apart the wheel hub, which will almost certainly require new ball bearings and perhaps new "cones" as well. I'd stick with just replacing the cassette for now if you don't have experience servicing bearings (or can book time with a mechanic).

Comment: Your were right, Armand!  I removed the well worn old cassette, ordered a new one. While waiting for the cassette to arrive, I removed the skewer, cleaned up and inspected the cones and 18 ball bearings,  0.250" with micrometer.  Surprisingly good condition.   Repacked the assembly with white lithium grease.  New cassette  (SRAM PG-850-8Spd, 11-32T) easily installed.  Derailleurs a little tricky to set up.  Rode bike for 13.5  test miles. Additional  adjustments will be necessary.